# Find side $h$ for the triangle described in the figure

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Find side $h$ for the triangle described in the figure below.

[image]

From a math-contest. Please point out if it is duplicate. Hints and/or solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$3=h\tan(\theta) $$

$$8=h\tan (\theta+\alpha) $$

$$12=h\tan (2\theta+\alpha) $$

$$=h\frac {\tan (\theta)+\tan (\theta+\alpha)}{1-\tan (\theta)\tan (\theta+\alpha)} $$

$$=\frac {11}{1-\frac {24}{h^2}} $$
thus

$$12 (h^2-24)=11h^2$$
and
$$h=12\sqrt {2}$$